# Would having interned or worked at BARC, ISRO or DRDO make a person ineligible for US visa?

Tags: usa, citizenship, student-visa, indian-citizens, refusal

I came across a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/india/comments/p8m0xx/would_working_in_drdo_as_an_intern_make_me/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=comments_view_all) where the OP was concerned whether doing an internship at BARC, ISRO or DRDO would cause him/her to be ineligible for US visa. OP stated that a friend of his/her uncle who worked for a year or two at DRDO was denied visa because of his job history. Another commenter anecdoted that a friend who had done a project for ISRO was denied visa because she mentioned it in her interview.

Is there any rule which denies visa to students who had done internship in the above mentioned organizations? Are such students and ex-employees of the above organizations automatically ineligible for US visa or citizenship?

Abbreviations:

- BARC is [Bhabha Atomic Research Centre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_Atomic_Research_Centre)
- ISRO is [Indian Space Research Organisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Space_Research_Organisation)
- DRDO is [Defence Research and Development Organisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_Research_and_Development_Organisation)

Comment: The abbreviations or acronyms BARC, ISRO, and DRDO are unclear to those of us (like, for example, me) who do not know them. Writing the name out fully would be better than making each reader research the words in your question in order to know what you're asking about.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica sorry about that. I have fixed it.

Comment: Even if there are no formal rules banning people associated with certain listed institutions from being *eligible* to any visa, it's possible that a specific application would be rejected based on that. In another country I am familiar with, applications from nationals of certain countries to work on technologies deemed sensitive is subject to an additional review by an intelligence agency. Maybe that's what happened here?

Comment: It doesn't mean that the same person couldn't receive a visitor visa, a visa to work, say, as an engineer in a completely different domain, or apply for citizenship based on marriage. I don't know how the US handles this but it seems to be the most likely explanation to me.

Comment: Does the US actually give such specific reason(s) for refusals? IIRC (quite possibly I don’t) there’ve been quite a few questions on TravelSE relating to refusals where the OP wasn’t given an explicit reason and so was struggling to understand what to do to address it